# Fast way to search through this php array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, search, associative-array

I have the following php array;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'records' => array(
            'id' => '25',
            'parent_id' => '1',
            'address' => '896167',
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'records' => array(
            'id' => '26',
            'parent_id' => '2',
            'address' => '890812',
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'records' => array(
            'id' => '28',
            'parent_id' => '16',
            'address' => '8A3813',
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'records' => array(
            'id' => '29',
            'parent_id' => '17',
            'address' => '8A3914',
        )
    )
)
```

Suppose I want to find which key has '`id' => '29'`, what is a fast way to search through this array and return the correct key? In this case, the correct answer is 3.

EDIT: Would anyone advise whether using foreach to loop through the array or using array_search would be faster? Or are they about the same speed?

Comment: Are they always sorted by id?

Comment: @Mooseman: id is the primary key used in the table.

Comment: If this doesn't have to be very complex, just iterate through every "object" (that with the keys 0, 1, 2, 3). But if there are really a lot of objects, then you should use a fast algorithm for that.

Comment: wow **keyword fastest**, wheres your attempt? whats your reason why fastest?

Comment: @Ghost: I am trying to use foreach loop. Working on it now. Actually, it is hard to be sure whether a method can be the fastest. I have problems with a very slow query. Trying to speed things up.

Comment: I have changed the question to use a fast method. No need to be the fastest because ... who knows for sure?

Comment: well if you want a definitive answer, then just benchmark it, foreach vs for vs while vs array functions, test their microtimes starting and ending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['records']['id'] == '29') break;
}
echo $key;
```

Completes in linear time.

If your array is sorted by ID you can do a binary search instead which will complete in logarithmic time.

```
function binary_search($needle, $haystack) {
    $min = 0;
    $max = count($haystack);
    while ($max >= $min)
    {
        $mid = (int) (($min + $max) / 2);
        if ($haystack[$mid]['records']['id'] == $needle) return $mid;
        else if ($haystack[$mid]['records']['id'] < $needle) $min = $mid + 1;
        else $max = $mid - 1;
    }
    // $needle was not found
    return false;
}

echo binary_search('29', $data);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you will be doing *many* such searches, it is best to create a *reverse lookup* array.

That is, you do the slow linear work *one time*, after that, it is a quick hash (associative array) lookup.

One time:

```
$id2index = array();
foreach ($data as $index => $value) {
    $id2index[$value->id] = $index;
}
```

Used many times - find index for given id:

```
$index = $id2index[$id];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `array_search()` on your data structure. Your `foreach` solution has a time complexity of `O(n)` (and so would have `array_search()` as well).

You said the records are ordered by its id. Then you are able to do [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) which performs much better with `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the binairy searching algorithm like this:

```php
$searchableArray = array(
                    0 => array(
                        'records' => array(
                            'id' => '25',
                            'parent_id' => '1',
                            'address' => '896167',
                        )
                    ),
                    1 => array(
                        'records' => array(
                            'id' => '26',
                            'parent_id' => '2',
                            'address' => '890812',
                        )
                    ),
                    2 => array(
                        'records' => array(
                            'id' => '28',
                            'parent_id' => '16',
                            'address' => '8A3813',
                        )
                    ),
                    3 => array(
                        'records' => array(
                            'id' => '29',
                            'parent_id' => '17',
                            'address' => '8A3914',
                        )
                    )
                );

$foundKey = findKey( $searchableArray, 29 );
echo "Found key: " . $foundKey;

function findKey( $searchableArray, $key ){
    $splittedArray = splitArray( $searchableArray );
    if( isInLeftChunk( $splittedArray[0], $key ) ){
        if( ! isOnlyElement( $splittedArray[0] ) ){
            return findKey( $splittedArray[0], $key );
        }
        return key( $splittedArray[0] );
    }
    elseif( isInRightChunk( $splittedArray[1], $key ) ){
        if( ! isOnlyElement( $splittedArray[1] ) ){
            return findKey( $splittedArray[1], $key );
        }
        return key( $splittedArray[1] );
    }

    // Element not found
    return false;
}

function isOnlyElement( $arrayChunk ){
    return count( $arrayChunk ) == 1;
}

function isInLeftChunk( $arrayChunk, $key ){
    end( $arrayChunk );
    $latestKey = key( $arrayChunk );
    if( is_int( $latestKey )){
        return $arrayChunk[ $latestKey ]['records']['id'] >= $key;
    }
    return $arrayChunk[ $latestKey ]['id'] >= $key;
}

function isInRightChunk( $arrayChunk, $key ){
    reset( $arrayChunk );
    $firstKey = key( $arrayChunk );
    if( is_int( $firstKey )){
        return $arrayChunk[$firstKey]['records']['id'] <= $key;
    }
    return $arrayChunk[ $firstKey ]['id'] <= $key;
}

function splitArray( $unsplittedArray ){
    $arrayLenght = count( $unsplittedArray );
    if( $arrayLenght == 1 ){
        return array_chunk( $unsplittedArray, $arrayLenght, true );
    }

    $odd = $arrayLenght % 2 != 0;
    if( $odd ){
        $arrayLenght += 1;
    }
    $arrayLenght = $arrayLenght * 0.5;

    return array_chunk( $unsplittedArray, $arrayLenght, true );
}
```